# WSO2 BAM - Sending KPI data from WSO2 ESB to BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I am trying to send KPI data of WSO2 ESB to WSO2 BAM for Analysing that KPI's

Consider in WSo2 ESB handles below message,

```
<Transport type='KPN'>
  <Tickets>3"<"/Tickets>
</Transport>
```

As KPI I need to sent the data's

```
/Transport@type
/Transport/Tickets
```

to WSO2 BAM.

1. I am seeking examples of sending KPIs of WSO2 ESB to WSO2 BAM
2. Also if install Mediation Data Agent in WSO2 ESB and do the configuration as mentioned in http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Setting+up+Mediation+Data+Agent

Will I be able to sent the KPI Data from WSO2 ESB to WSO2 BAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BAM Mediator Publisher to publish custom data from ESB. See http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator on how to setup BAM mediator. There you can define properties to be published to BAM within a stream. These properties can be collected from doing XPath on the message.

Comment: Okay,Thank you! I will try this out and keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Mediation Data Agent is for collecting statistics related to mediation data in ESB. As chamibuddhika mentioned, you can use [BAM mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator) which will collect properties from the Messageontext of ESB. And also it captures some other fixed information such as message header/body etc. As an exercise you can try the [Activity Monitoring Toolbox](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Activity+Monitoring+Toolbox) with BAM mediator. But the XPath feature mentioned by chamibuddhika is not available in BAM 2.0.1. It will be implemented in future.